# Функция explode(). Почему не работает со спецсимволом '\t'?

Tags: php

Если непосредственно знак табуляции скопировать в аргумент функции то она работает, а вот при использовании \t нет. Почему так?

Comment: потому что надо `explode("\t",$array)` в двойных ковычках писать.

Comment: Интерполяция работает только в двойных (`"`) кавычках. В одинарных (`'`) - это просто слеш и t символы.

Comment: @IvanSkald, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Интерполяция работает только в двойных (`"`) кавычках. В одинарных (`'`) - это просто слеш и `t` символы.

```
$str = 'one two three';

var_dump(explode('\t', $str)); // Не сработает
var_dump(explode("\t", $str)); // Заработало!
```

http://ideone.com/fMIcjW